# Different algorithms are giving different no of outliers at the same contamination level in pyod

Tags: python, anomaly-detection

I am using pyod for anomaly detection and for different algorithms,I am getting different no of outliers at the same `contamination` level for example `abod` is giving `5` outliers and `IForest` is giving `9` outliers at a `contamination` level of `0.05`.
In the documentation I read like no of outliers are equal to `total no of samples * contamination`,then the number of outliers from all the algorithms at the same contamination level should be equal right,please suggest me on this.

Comment: Is this when you evaluate on your training set?

Comment: How many samples in your training set?

Comment: @JonNordby,Thanks for the response,my training set consists of 180 samples and I did fit the algorithms on the training data and got the anomalies by using classifier.labels_. However I observed that if scores are same for more than mentioned percentage of outliers,then this is happening ,in my case after the scores of five anomalies, there are 7 data points with same anomaly score, since it is not possible to select the 4 data points out of 7 as they have same anomaly score, only the top five are getting returned. This is only my assumption, please correct me if I am wrong.